# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Binding to List<int> (generic lists) property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

I am trying to implement a controller method inside of NopCommerce under ASP.NET Core 3.1 that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CustomerSchool/Update")]
public IActionResult Update(CustomerSchoolMappingModel model)
{

}
```

my model looks like this:

```
public class CustomerSchoolMappingModel : BaseNopModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public List<int> SchoolIds { get; set; } = new List<int>();
}
```

When I submit a http POST with the following form data:

```
CustomerId: 1
SchoolIds[0]: 2
SchoolIds[1]: 3
```

My properties are successfully binding but not the SchoolIds property collection which is always returning empty.

I suspect that NopCommerce has replaced the default modelbinders (which I believe support this functionality by default in ASP.NET) but I am not 100% sure how to correctly replace/implement this functionality.

I believe using a custom `IModelBinderProvider` to fix this issue could work but I am wondering what is the correct/best way to fix this problem and ensure I can correctly bind generic lists using the `name[x] form schema` in my ASP.NET Core application?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `[FromForm]` attribute on method argument in the controller and the argument name in your request. I've never used NopCommerce. Here are correct collection formats when sending form data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections. This request's body should work:

```
model.CustomerId=1&model.SchoolIds[]=12&model.SchoolIds[]=321
```

This code works fine for me without any custom model binders:

```cs
public class FormDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> ListOfIds { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FormController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("post")]
    public ActionResult Post([FromForm] FormDto dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto, Formatting.Indented));
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I tested it with Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell:

```bsh
iwr -uri http://localhost:5000/api/form/post -Method Post -Body 'dto.Id=13&dto.ListOfIds[]=1&dto.ListOfIds[]=2&dto.ListOfIds[]=34' -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Output in console:

```json
{
  "Id": 13,
  "ListOfIds": [
    1,
    2,
    34
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed breakdown, and you are most likely correct, as mentioned I would expect this to work in a default project HOWEVER I am using this in NopCommerce which clearly messes with the default binding.

I have tried using [FromForm] and can confirm that it doesn't help in my scenario

Comment: Thanks for upvote. Have you tried adding the argument name (`model`) in the request? I gave an example in my answer. When I tested it I had to add `dto` in my request's body.

Comment: I haven't, but after performing more research it looks like NopCommerce implements its own completely custom model binding. I should have an answer that I will post soon which shows how to resolve this problem for Nop but your answer is probably most appropriate to others who run into this situation outside of NopCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone interested it seems to boil down to Nop not liking using Generic lists.

I reviewed the default binders used by Nop from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.binders?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and
I was able to successfully resolve my problem by changing my model to this:

```
public class CustomerSchoolMappingModel : BaseNopModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> SchoolIds { get; set; } = new List<int>();

}
```